# Hineingucken/schauen

Tags: word-usage, german-to-english, colloquial

Ich habe ein paar Fragen zu "hineingucken/schauen". Was heißen diese Worte eigentlich? Vor allem wenn man "mal kurz reingucken/schauen" oder sowas Ähnliches sagt. Wird es irgendwie ins Englische als "take a quick look" übersetzt? Kann man es daneben auch im Sinne von "drop by / pop in / have a look" verwenden? Beispielsweise "Da unten gibt’s eine Party los ("los" passt dazu, oder?), können wir mal kurz reingucken/schauen, wenn du willst".

Comment: "los" passt hier nicht. Man kann sagen "da unten ist was los", aber "was los" ist ein fester Begriff. Eine Party ist nicht "los". Man kann sagen "eine Party steigt" oder einfach "da ist eine Party".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hineingucken* heißt ganz allgemein, in einen Raum, Behälter, Fernglas etc. zu schauen. Meist kann man das mit *to look in(to)* übersetzen.

*(Mal) kurz reingucken*, oft auch *(mal) kurz vorbeischauen* bedeutet umgangssprachlich, zu einem Treffen oder einer Feier zu gehen, wobei man sich relativ sicher ist, dass man nicht lange bleiben wird. Das wäre dann die Entsprechung für das englische *to drop by*.